# Chapter header design

Tags: pdftex, chapters, thesis

Guys can someone help me have a design like this?

[image]

MWE

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
    \definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
    \newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{État de l’art en factorisation
matricielle}
    \blindtext
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `titlesec`, here's a solution with this package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Huge\bfseries\filleft}{\chaptername~\thechapter \hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{3ex}{\Huge\bfseries}[\hrulefill]

\begin{document}

\chapter{État de l’art en factorisation\\ matricielle}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes this is exactly what i wanted. too bad i already submitted the final manuscript. but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, try :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
            \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    %\vspace*{1\p@}%
    \hrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
            \scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    %\vspace*{1\p@}%
    \hrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\chapter*{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Seems rather close. The code is due to [Vincent Zoonekynd](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html).

This EDIT takes care of starred chapters.

Comment: cool. any idea why it doesnt affect my other chapters like abstract and acknowledgements?

Comment: My code affects numbered chapters

Comment: how do i make it affect my unnumbered chapters like abstract?

Comment: @FaroukYahaya See my EDIT. Bizarre to have the abstract as a chapter, I think.